# SQL query update nvarchar with XML contents add missing attribute to node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I have an nvarchar column with XML contents. Not sure if it needs to be cast to XML or not. All the XML content is formatted the same except a number of records need to be modified where the first node needs an attribute added to it:

```
<MyFirstNode SomeAttribute="value" SomeOtherAttribute="anothervalue">
```

update to:

```
<MyFirstNode SomeAttribute="value" AddThisAttribute="nicevalue" SomeOtherAttribute="anothervalue">
```

How can i update all the required nodes with the AddThisAttribute="nicevalue" ? All need the same attribute and value.

Comment: Is there a reason your column is NVARCHAR and not XML if it contains XML? I suppose your choices come down to converting it to XML and using the `modify('insert attribute AddThisAttribute {("nicevalue")} into (*)[1]')` function or writing a (possibly complex) `STUFF` statement for your column as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actually going to be interpreted as XML, you don't neccessarily have to insert AddThisAttribute="nicevalue" in the middle of the list of attributes; one option is to do a simple

```
UPDATE myTable
SET XMLColumn = REPLACE(XMLColumn, '<MyFirstNode ', '<MyFirstNode AddThisAttribute="nicevalue" ')
```

This might be easier than trying to insert the value, especially if SomeAttribute and SomeOtherAttribute change in each row.

Alternately,

```
UPDATE myTable
SET XMLColumn = REPLACE(XMLColumn, ' SomeOtherAttribute=', ' AddThisAttribute="nicevalue"  SomeOtherAttribute=')
```

could work, though if "SomeOtherAttribute" appears in other node types other than MyFirstNode, this might make undesired changes.

Comment: I set this as the correct answer but this is an nvarchar and i think you would need to cast it as XML before you could update it as an XML column. Thanks!